# Can js scripts interfere with php?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm cobbling together a website for a committee and i've taken an iso box template and now I want to generate the profile cards from a json file. However when I load the page the php fails to produce the cards but there are no obvious errors in it as far as I am aware.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("data/committee.json"), true);
if ($json !== false) {
    foreach ($json as $officer => $content) {
        $role = $content["role"];
        $name = $content["name"];
        $tags = $content["tags"];

        echo "<div class='iso-box $tags col-md-3 col-sm-3'>";
            echo "<div class='portfolio-thumb'>";
            echo "<img src=\"files/committee_pictures/$role.jpg\" class='img-responsive' alt='Portfolio'>";
                echo "<div class='portfolio-overlay'>";
                        echo "<div class='portfolio-item'>";
                        echo "<a href=mailto:$role.@website.co.uk><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i></a>";
                        echo "<h2>$officer</h2>";
                        echo "<p> $name </p>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
      }
    }
?>
```

Comment: No.  Generally speaking, javascript runs on the client after PHP has already finished processing and sent the output from the server to the client.  They run on two separate systems.

Comment: Yes javascript can interfare with it. If there are code below where the error occurs, then the others wont work resulting in a failed webload.

Ecample you have ` echo "<div class='iso-box $tags col-md-3 col-sm-3'>";`
$tags can be like manager, employees, etc and you have javascript code working with classes if an error was before that then your cards for manager or employees wont display or function as it should

Comment: did you set error reporting to catch and display and view your console?

Comment: @Fred-ii- sadly i'm not experienced enough to know what that means. I'm learning as I go and testing by directly uploading to the server and viewing the webpage....

Comment: Are you successfully retrieving the file contents from your JSON file? Are you able to print the result following the `json_decode()` call? (i.e. var_dump($json) after it's declared)?

Comment: Error reporting => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you mention JS. That if there was a conflict/error, then those are to be  viewed in the developer console.

Comment: try  print_r($json) before  if and see what you are getting . NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded!!

Comment: I think what you're looking to use here is ajax, sounds like it (to me) if you intend on using JS, that I don't see in the post. This being besides the valid comments given by others, yet one that states otherwise is not entirely correct. They can run together, it just depends on *how* they're used and doesn't produce (syntax) errors.

Comment: you have answers below now; I'll let you go through them, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`but there are no obvious errors` - yeah, because your code actively tries to hide/ignore errors. try instead of hiding errors, throw exceptions whenever an error occur, such code is much easier to debug, errors does not silently propagate (as is happening with your current code), and errors are caught as early as possible, like this:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode ( file_get_contents ( "data/committee.json" ), true );
if (empty ( $json )) {
    throw new \RuntimeException ( 'failed to parse the json!: ' . json_last_error () . ': ' . json_last_error_msg () );
}
foreach ( $json as $officer => $content ) {
    foreach ( array (
            'role',
            'name',
            'tags' 
    ) as $required ) {
        if (! array_key_exists ( $required, $content )) {
            throw new \Exception ( 'invalid data! officer missing ' . $required );
        }
        ${$required} = $content [$required];
    }
    echo "<div class='iso-box $tags col-md-3 col-sm-3'>";
    echo "<div class='portfolio-thumb'>";
    echo "<img src=\"files/committee_pictures/$role.jpg\" class='img-responsive' alt='Portfolio'>";
    echo "<div class='portfolio-overlay'>";
    echo "<div class='portfolio-item'>";
    echo "<a href=mailto:$role.@website.co.uk><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i></a>";
    echo "<h2>$officer</h2>";
    echo "<p> $name </p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

edit: you're obviously constructing HTML here, and unless role, name, and tags, are already pre-html-encoded inside that json, you should html encode them before putting them into html, this will protects against hackers trying to inject code via $name (or any other variable), and protect against tags accidentally including characters with special meaning in HTML, for example:

```
function tohtml(string $str): string {
    return htmlentities ( $str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true );
}
...
 ${$required}=tohtml($content[$required]);
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be very difficult for Javascript and PHP to interact unless you were intentionally making them do so.

PHP is always going to be executed on the server side, and Javascript will typically be processed on the client side, after your PHP has finished.

If you're not seeing any results from your PHP here, then it's definitely an error with your PHP code.

I'd recommend you render `$json` and `$json !== false` as text to troubleshoot. This variable is definitely either empty, false, or not formatted in the way you think it is, causing an error when you try to loop over it.

You should also figure out where your PHP/server logs are saved, because that's where the output of any errors would be.

Comment: Since JSON is not expected to be scalar, echoing is not recommended.  var_dump() or print_r() would be much better.